# Relationship Many-To-One how to save

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I've searched on google and mostly of examples didn't helped or I'm doing wrong what I want. So I quite don't understand how GORM saves in this type of relationship, how I can save new event that is related on the user? the `addToEvent` doesn't work.

```
class User{
Long id
String name
Long codeUser
StatusType statusType
static hasMany = [event: Event]
static constraints = {
    statusType(nullable: true)
    name(nullable: true)
}
class Event{
Long id
String name
String startDate
String description
static belongsTo = [user:User]
static constraints = {
    name(nullable: true)
    startDate(nullable: true)
    description(nullable: true)
}

def createEvent(){
    def data = JSON.parse(params.data)
    def user = User.findByCodeUser(data.codeUser)
    def event = new Event(name: data.name, startDate: data.start_time, description: data.description)
    //removed the user: user
    user.addToEvent(event)
    user.save(flush: true)
}
```

The error is this: `Message: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.addToEvent() is applicable for argument types: (project.web.Event) values: [project.web.Event : (unsaved)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As outlined in the [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/GORM.html#manyToMany) you need to use the addTo* method to save the relationship correctly through GORM.

```
class User{
    ...//attributes
    Long codeUser
    static hasMany = [event: Event]
}
class Event{
    ...//attributes
    Long codeEvent
    static belongsTo = [user:User]
}

def user = User.findByCodeUser(params.codeUser)

def event = new Event(codeEvent: params.codeEvent)
user.addToEvent(event)
user.save(flush: true)
```

Notice that you don't have to set the `User` property of the `Event` and saving the `User` will also save the `Event`.

Finally, as a style guide you typically want to name your collections in the plural form.

```
static hasMany = [events: Event]
```

Comment: I tried to use `addTo` method, but it's giving the error: `No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.addToEvent()` and `cannot resolve symbol addToEvent` as you mentioned the code.

Comment: Then something odd is going on with your User.findByCodeUser as it should return the first matching instance of that domain class. What version of Grails are you using?

Comment: It's returning packagename.domain 1, grails 2.3.6

Comment: you aren't defining the "event" property in your domain class besides the hasMany are you? If so, that may be the issue.

Comment: Event event you mean, if yes, i didnt.

Comment: Hmm, something very odd is going on since the toString appears to be correct. Can you post your full Domains and Controller method/action?

Comment: Wow, I made a huge mistake there. Thanks for the answer, the problem is that I changed the method without noticing.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out!